# Feed Me with Related Entries Fields - One to Many Relationship

Tags: plugin-feedme, json

I'm using **Feed Me** to populate content for a "Meetings" section in my site. One of the fields in this section is "Meeting Attendees", which is an entries field relating to a Contacts Section.

I have a JSON file that contains a unique Meeting ID, and this Meeting ID could map to several Contacts. In a simplified form, my JSON file format is essentially this:

```
[
    {
        "Meeting Title" : "Project Kickoff"
        "Meeting Attendee" : "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "Meeting Title" : "Project Kickoff"
        "Meeting Attendee" : "Jane Smith"
    },
    {
        "Meeting Title" : "Project Kickoff"
        "Meeting Attendee" : "Jim Brown"
    }
]
```

You'll see in this simplified example that three Contacts need to be related to the "Project Kickoff" Meeting entry. I have my "Meeting Attendees" entries field configured with no limit on number of selectable entries, and can add multiple entries without issue when entering data manually.

However when I run Feed Me on a data set like the one above, Feed Me seemingly overwrites/replaces the entries rather than adding each as a separate relation. e.g. When Feed Me has completed processing the above dataset, my "Project Kickoff" entry will only have one attendee related ("Jim Brown" in this case - or whatever the last value in the dataset happens to be). For the example data above, I would expect to see all three "Meeting Attendees" names related to the "Project Kickoff" meeting entry.

Is there a way to configure either Feed Me or my JSON data to produce the intended result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not define the attendees as an array in your JSON? This should allow multiples to be added to your field.

```
[
    {
        "Meeting Title" : "Project Kickoff"
        "Meeting Attendees" : ["John Doe", "Jane Smith", "Jim Brown"]
    }
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the API from which I grab this data isn't controlled by me, but I'll try writing something to pre-process the data prior to import.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that. Get someone to rewrite the API!

Comment: Andy's method was correct. Once I refactored the JSON feed into the format Andy described, the records came in without issue.